# gcc has a memory leak?

Tags: gcc, memory-leaks, clang, valgrind

I've been trying to be more meticulous lately about memory management in my code. Just for a laugh, I wrote a simple C source file containing only one function, and used valgrind to see if the C compiler itself had any leaks. To my great surprise, it did!

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes  gcc -c example.c
    ...bunch of junk...
==4587== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4587==    definitely lost: 4,207 bytes in 60 blocks
==4587==    indirectly lost: 56 bytes in 5 blocks
==4587==      possibly lost: 27 bytes in 2 blocks
==4587==    still reachable: 29,048 bytes in 47 blocks
==4587==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Clang had leaks too, of only 68 bytes though, all of them reachable.

I thought that if your code has memory leaks, you get thrown in solitary confinement for every byte you lose. Have I misunderstood the implications of memory leaks? Are they actually sort of tolerable as long as it's not a long-running program? Is this actually just valgrind being wrong?